# Bamboo docker build failing?

Tags: docker, bamboo, bamboo-specs

I have a docker container:

```
/usr/bin/docker run --volume /home/bamboo/builds/xml-data/build-dir/360449/WEBSITE-BD-JOB3:/home/bamboo/builds/xml-data/build-dir/360449/WEBSITE-BD-JOB3 --volume /var/atlassian/application-data/bamboo/temp:/var/atlassian/application-data/bamboo/temp --detach --name 511d9b8d-cd36-4d53-92c9-78a94c2be6795570564 --net=host shamilnunhuck/kaniko-debug:shell tail -f /dev/null
```

and I assume Bamboo is trying to copy my script over?

```
/usr/bin/docker cp /opt/atlassian/bamboo/temp/initialiseDockerContainer.sh7168219084128755568.tmp 511d9b8d-cd36-4d53-92c9-78a94c2be6795570564:/tmp/initialiseContainer.sh
```

However, it fails:

```
Error: No such container:path: 511d9b8d-cd36-4d53-92c9-78a94c2be6795570564:/tmp
Exit code: 1, output: STDOUT:  Beginning to execute external process for build 'Shamil Website - Build - Publish Image #25 (WEBSITE-BD-JOB3-25)'\n ... running command line: \n/usr/bin/docker cp /opt/atlassian/bamboo/temp/initialiseDockerContainer.sh7168219084128755568.tmp 511d9b8d-cd36-4d53-92c9-78a94c2be6795570564:/tmp/initialiseContainer.sh\n ... in: /home/bamboo/builds/xml-data/build-dir/360449/WEBSITE-BD-JOB3\nSTDERR: Error: No such container:path: 511d9b8d-cd36-4d53-92c9-78a94c2be6795570564:/tmp
Failed to start docker container 511d9b8d-cd36-4d53-92c9-78a94c2be6795570564
com.atlassian.bamboo.docker.DockerException: Error running Docker run command
        at com.atlassian.bamboo.docker.DockerContainerServiceImpl.run(DockerContainerServiceImpl.java:130)
        at com.atlassian.bamboo.v2.build.agent.docker.DockerContainerControllerImpl.startContainerIfRequired(DockerContainerControllerImpl.java:98)
        at com.atlassian.bamboo.v2.build.agent.DefaultBuildAgent.build(DefaultBuildAgent.java:154)
        at com.atlassian.bamboo.v2.build.agent.BuildAgentControllerImpl.lambda$waitAndPerformBuild$0(BuildAgentControllerImpl.java:130)
        at com.atlassian.bamboo.variable.CustomVariableContextImpl.withVariableSubstitutor(CustomVariableContextImpl.java:118)
        at com.atlassian.bamboo.v2.build.agent.BuildAgentControllerImpl.waitAndPerformBuild(BuildAgentControllerImpl.java:124)
        at com.atlassian.bamboo.v2.build.agent.DefaultBuildAgent.lambda$start$0(DefaultBuildAgent.java:108)
        at com.atlassian.bamboo.utils.BambooRunnables$1.run(BambooRunnables.java:48)
        at com.atlassian.bamboo.security.ImpersonationHelper.runWith(ImpersonationHelper.java:26)
        at com.atlassian.bamboo.security.ImpersonationHelper.runWithSystemAuthority(ImpersonationHelper.java:17)
        at com.atlassian.bamboo.security.ImpersonationHelper$1.run(ImpersonationHelper.java:41)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.atlassian.utils.process.ProcessException: Error executing /usr/bin/docker cp /opt/atlassian/bamboo/temp/initialiseDockerContainer.sh7168219084128755568.tmp 511d9b8d-cd36-4d53-92c9-78a94c2be6795570564:/tmp/initialiseContainer.sh
        at com.atlassian.bamboo.docker.DockerContainerServiceImpl.execute(DockerContainerServiceImpl.java:302)
        at com.atlassian.bamboo.docker.DockerContainerServiceImpl.execute(DockerContainerServiceImpl.java:273)
        at com.atlassian.bamboo.docker.DockerContainerServiceImpl.run(DockerContainerServiceImpl.java:112)
        ... 11 more
```

Bamboo can delete the container, so I assume it's still running. Any ideas why it's failing?

Bamboo specs:

```
Publish Image:
  tasks:
    - artifact-download:
        source-plan: WEBSITE-BD
        artifacts:
          - name: release
    - script:
      - echo "{\"auths\":{\"r.gcr.io\":{\"username\":\"kubernetes\",\"password\":\"${bamboo.CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD}\"}}}" > /kaniko/.docker/config.json
      - /kaniko/executor
        --cache=true \
        --context . \
        --dockerfile ./release/Dockerfile \
        --destination r.gcr.io/hadcm3/personal-website:${bamboo.planRepository.revision}
  docker:
    image: shamilnunhuck/kaniko-debug:shell
```

Comment: Are you using the docker task in Bamboo or running `docker` directly from a script?

Comment: @Raffi I'm using Bamboo specs to run the job isolating in docker

Comment: my question was about if you are using the [docker cli task](https://docs.atlassian.com/bamboo-specs-docs/6.10.3/specs.html?java#dockerbuildimagetask) but this does not seem to be the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command

```
/usr/bin/docker cp \
    /opt/atlassian/bamboo/temp/initialiseDockerContainer.sh7168219084128755568.tmp \
    511d9b8d-cd36-4d53-92c9-78a94c2be6795570564:/tmp/initialiseContainer.sh
```

indicates that it attempts to copy your script into the container. The error

```
No such container:path: 511d9b8d-cd36-4d53-92c9-78a94c2be6795570564:/tmp
```

is certainly emitted by `docker` and not Bamboo. So it seems to me that:

- either `/tmp` does not exist in the container
- or the container did not start (immediate failure)

Comment: and can you do a `docker cp` of any file into `/tmp` with the same syntax as `511d9b8d-cd36-4d53-92c9-78a94c2be6795570564:/tmp/` ?

Comment: Looks like tmp was missing